# rails view without a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can rails handle creating a view without a controller?  For example, let say I have a page that just links to other pages, would I need to create a dummy controller for that, or could I just do something in my routes file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. All requests has to go through a controller.

I like to have a `PagesController`, with `map.page ":action", :controller => "pages"`. That way, I can create `app/views/pages/foo.erb` and have it available on `/foo` without any extra code.

Comment: Thoughtbot have a useful plugin for this: http://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage/tree/master

Comment: This seems outdated now...? It first said map is undefined. Then I added map as a parameter on top of routes.rb  |map| 

Then Rails gave a more elaborate error pointing me to this URL [the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3](https://blog.engineyard.com/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/)

Answer (score 29):

I like August's answer but I have a slightly different method.

Let's say you want to add

> /any/path/somefile.html.erb

but not add a controller...

You can just add folder to views called "application", create your file in that directory..

Then in your routes file just add

```
match '/any/path/somefile' => 'application#somefile'
```

Your erb still evaluates, you get your layout, and you can create any path you want...
(all this does is remove the need for the pages controller)

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be adding a static html file in your /public directory if you truly don't need it as part of your application.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a brave soul. You can try edge rails 3. Katz demonstrated this possibility on his blog. Here is the link:

http://yehudakatz.com/2009/07/19/rails-3-the-great-decoupling/

Answer (score 1):

No. All requests have to go through a controller.

If you have a page like `index.html.erb` and `contact.html.erb` in your view folder. You need to create a dummy controller called `contact`. Then you can link to the `contact.html.erb` from the `index.html.erb`. And give the link as `<%= link_to 'contact', :controller => "ads", :action => "contact" %>` here "ads"->controller name.